# Dependency injection if a class needs to create multiple instances of another class when required in a method

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Hi I am learning the best way to do dependency injection and also using IoC containers to resolve dependencies. however most of the examples that i have come across a class only needs a single instance of its dependency class and this dependency is injected into the constructor. But my scenarios is a little different. I have a  class with a method which is continuously doing some work in a loop and foreach iteration in the loop i need to create a new instance of a different class. How do I go about doing dependency injection in this scenario?  how can an IoC container resolve this ?

Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like dkatzel said, use a `factory`. This is the way I go about it. If you were creating instances of say, `BaseViewModel`:

```
public interface IViewModelFactory {
    T Create<T>() where T : BaseViewModel;
}

public class ViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory {
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseViewModel>> _factories;

    public ViewModelFactory(Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseViewModel>> factories) {
        _factories = factories;
    }

    public T Create<T>() where T : BaseViewModel {
        return _factories[typeof (T)]() as T;
    }
}
```

So now we have an injectable factory that can be configured to create and return anything that implements `BaseViewModel`.

In IoC we need to configure the types to return so imagine these view models (and note the dependency in the second view model):

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel {
    // ...
}

public class FirstViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    // ...
}

public class SecondViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private readonly ISomeDependency _injectedDependency;

    public SeoncdViewModel(ISomeDependency dependency) {
        _injectedDependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

And (using Autofac) we configure it like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register(b => {

    var factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseViewModel>> {
        { typeof (FirstViewModel), () => new FirstViewModel() },
        { typeof (SecondViewModel), () => new SecondViewModel(b.Resolve<ISomeDependency>()) },
    };

    return new ViewModelFactory(factories);

}).As<IViewModelFactory>();
```

And now we can inject `IViewModelFactory` and create instances of `FirstViewModel` or `SecondViewModel`:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public readonly IViewModelFactory _factory;

    public SomeClass(IViewModelFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;

        var secondViewModel = _factory.Create<SecondViewModel>();
    }
}
```

The nice part is that IoC handles all of the dependencies. `SomeClass` just knows that it has a thing that can create a `SecondViewModel` so `SomeClass` doesn't need to know about `SecondViewModels` dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

inject an instance of a `Factory` which can create the objects you want:

```
void doLoop(){
 for(;;){
    MyObj obj = factory.createNew();

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have further scenario which [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672179/class-structure-for-decoupling-and-dependency-injection-in-windows-service-with) can you comment on that please ?